# Cannot apply path pattern for firestore in EventArc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, event-arc

I was trying to use EventArc to monitor Firestore changes, which will trigger a Cloud Run service.

It works by listening to Any Resource or specific resource name.

```
Resource name
projects/PROJECT_Id/databases/(default)
```

[image]

It works, but it will listen to all changes in firestore. However, I want to filter the event to a specific collection. I have tried a few combinations to the pattern, and none of them works. E.g.

```
projects/PROJECT_Id/databases/(default)/users/*
projects/PROJECT_Id/databases/(default)/users/{user}
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOR8K.png) you shared, under the “Resource” section you selected “specific resource” instead can you try to change it to a “path pattern” and you will be able to write a specific path that the trigger object needs to respect.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://atamel.dev/posts/2022/03-02_path_patterns_eventarc/) for Applying a path pattern when filtering in Eventarc.

You can also check out the AuditLog step of [Trigger Cloud Run with events from Eventarc](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-events?hl=en#9) codelab for an example on how to use path patterns.

Comment: Thanks, even though in the image I set specific resource. I did it with the same configuration for the path pattern. It doesn't return anything. Does it work for you?

Comment: Instead of giving default, can you try giving the database ID in place of default like if your databaseId is demo then your database will be having path databases/demo

Comment: Meanwhile try with this path: `projects/PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/users/{userId}` for any changes to a document in users collections having userId

Comment: There's no event yet. I think they're not supported for firestore yet.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#specifying_the_document_path) To trigger the function, specify a document path to listen to. Functions only respond to document changes, and cannot monitor specific fields or collections.